# Is there a handy way of finding largest element in container using STL?

Tags: c++, algorithm, max, std

Is there a way finding largest container inside a container using STL? ATM, I have this
rather naïve way of doing it:

```
int main()
{
        std::vector<std::vector<int> > v;

        ...

        unsigned int h = 0;

        for (std::vector<std::vector<int> >::iterator i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
                if (*i.size() > h) {
                        h = *i.size();
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: Largest container or size of the largest?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can always use [std::max_element](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element) and pass a custom comparator that compares the size of two `std::vector<int>` as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered sorting the container using the STL sort methods?

Answer (score 0):

You could use quick select, and then select the value on the extreme end:

[Quick Select](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~stbird/Tutorials/QuickSelect.html)